Why do shared memory segments run longer than pipe when transferring big data?
I am writing a lab on operating systems. You need to write two programs that transmit data using pipe and shared memory segments. It is necessary to compare the transfer time and come to the conclusion that the shared memory segments work faster with big data. But it turns out the opposite. What is the problem in my code? What am I doing wrong?
I calculate the working time as the end of reading minus the beginning of writing
UPD: I listened to the comments and changed the code, add new result
CODE PIPE:
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define COUNT 6

int main()
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE
    int fd[2], nread, pid, status, base = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        int size = 8*base; // bytes
        base *= 16;
        pipe(fd);
        fcntl(fd[1], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);
        fcntl(fd[0], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);
        struct timespec t1, t2;
        pid = fork();
        
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // READ
            int tmp_size = 0;           
            close(fd[1]);               
            char *buf = (char *)malloc((size) * sizeof(char));
            while((nread = read(fd[0], buf, size)) != 0);

            free(buf);
            exit(1);    
        }
        else
        {
            // WRITE
            close(fd[0]);   
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);
        
            char *buf = (char *)malloc((size) * sizeof(char));
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                *(buf+j) = '1';
            }
            write(fd[1], buf, size);
            
            close(fd[1]);
            free(buf);
        }
        wait(&status);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t2);
        FILE *file = i == 0? fopen("program1_result", "w"): fopen("program1_result", "a+");
        char cur_time[150];
        sprintf(cur_time, "%ld nsec\n", 1000000000*(t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) + (t2.tv_nsec-t1.tv_nsec));
        if (file != NULL) fputs(cur_time, file);
        fclose(file);

    }
}

CODE SHARED MEMORY:
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wait.h>

#define COUNT 6

int main()
{
    int pid, status, shmid, sem, base = 1;
    char *shmPtr;
    key_t shm_keys[COUNT], sem_keys[COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        shm_keys[i] = ftok(".", (char)i);
        sem_keys[i] = ftok(".", 'a' + i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        int size = 8*base;      
        base *= 16;
        if ((shmid = shmget(shm_keys[i], size + 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) exit(1);
        shmPtr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        
        sem = semget(sem_keys[i], 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
        //struct timeval s, e;
        struct timespec t1, t2;
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {
            while(semctl(sem, 0, GETVAL) != 1);
            char *str = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(str, shmPtr);
            
            free(str);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {           
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);
            char *str = (char *)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                *(str+j) = '1';
            }
            *(str + size) = '\0';
            strcpy(shmPtr, str);
            
            semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, 1);
            free(str);          
        }   
        wait(&status);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t2);
        FILE *file = i == 0? fopen("program2_result", "w"): fopen("program2_result", "a+");
        char cur_time[150];
        sprintf(cur_time, "%ld nsec\n", 1000000000*(t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) + (t2.tv_nsec-t1.tv_nsec));
        if (file != NULL) fputs(cur_time, file);
        fclose(file);
        
        shmdt(shmPtr);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);
    }
    
    return 0;
}   


RESULT PIPE:

510134 nsec (8 bytes)
751695 nsec (128 bytes)
317859 nsec (2048 bytes)
372219 nsec (32768 bytes)
2158510 nsec (524288 bytes)
19722241 nsec (8388608 bytes)

RESULT SHARED MEMORY:

463168 nsec (8 bytes)
369917 nsec (128 bytes)
307799 nsec (2048 bytes)
361162 nsec (32768 bytes)
2019749 nsec (524288 bytes)
24943196 nsec (8388608 bytes)

New result:
|bytes    | pipe (nsec) | shm (nsec)|
|---------|-------------|-----------|
| 8       |   517516    |  489703   |
| 128     |   205485    |  440699   |
| 2048    |   374170    |  1162227  |
| 32768   |   584830    |  548490   |
| 524288  |   3162177   |  4010005  |
| 8388608 |   50293808  |  67142116 |

Please help understand what i do wrong.

Your difference on the last run is roughly 6 milliseconds. How many times did you test? What else is running on your computer? You have two separate processes running after you fork(). The operating system has to schedule the processing of each (along with scheduling everything else your operating system is doing at that time). You probably want to run about 100 tests and average the results to get a decent handle on what the relative times are. Then update the question with the new information. Other than the unused shmPtrWrite and shmPtrRead that code compiles fine.

Also note the parent process loop in your shared memory example includes an additional if (j == size) *(str+j) = '\0'; else *(str+j) = '1'; that is not present in your pipe code. Called 16 million times -- that can make some difference as well (though depending on processor and mitigations, branch prediction should minimize it)

Avoid using pow in integer calculations. Use int base =1; and base *= 16; size = 8 * base;

I'm confused. According to the times you posted, shared memory is faster (e.g. pipe=510134  shm=463168)

@CraigEstey This is only with small data; for larger ones, shared memory segments work slower

@DavidC.Rankin The browser is running, and the code itself runs on a virtual machine. Also, the speed of the shared memory segments at large sizes never falls below pipe. Therefore, even if you average the values, something is still going wrong. Updated the code and added new results

Okay, when you say "larger" data sets, do you just mean the 8M example or do you have other data sizes you are running against? Also what is it you are attempting to achieve? Why are you convinced that shared memory should be faster for larger data sets? With the pipe you are using the Linux syscalls read and write to move data. With shared memory you are treating the data as a nul-terminated string and moving data with strcpy(). That will be slower as it is scanning the buffer for a terminating '\0' character. This may be a better question on CodeReview.com rather than here.

Yes, i mean 8M. I am convinced that shared memory segments work faster because my teacher said so. This is the purpose of the work - to make sure of this in practice.

@bleedcloud Unfortunately, your program(s) don't measure things correctly. I've posted an answer with the corrected code (that shows shared is faster by 2x).


What is the problem in my code? What am I doing wrong?

Shared memory, particularly for large amounts of data is almost always faster.
The two programs are not equivalent in what they measure and this lead to erroneous results.
When corrected, the results clearly show that shared memory is faster (2x-3x faster). And, in terms of latency of the receiver, with shared memory, the receiver can start processing data much faster.
Consider the logical steps until the receiver can process data:

Sender creates the data in the buffer
For a pipe, sender does write which is a copying of the data. The receiver does a read which is [another] copying of the data.
For shared memory, no copy into the kernel or out of it is needed. Shared memory is "zero copy" as far as the kernel actions are concerned.

In other words, the pipe version does two [unnecessary] copy operations that the shm version doesn't.
Also, consider the "latency". The time from when the sender has filled the buffer until the receiver is [capable of] processing the data. The pipe version still has to write the data to the pipe. But, with the shm version, the receiver can start immediately after receiving the "notify" message (more on that in the update below).
Issues in the code ...

We want to measure just the transfer time from process to process.
In the shared memory version, the strcpy is extraneous. It defeats the purpose of using shared memory.
We need to operate directly on the shared buffer.
The strcpy is doing extra work that the pipe version isn't doing. That is, the pipe version is only doing read -- no processing of the data.
To mitigate the effects of timeslicing and system loading, we should do the same test multiple times and take the minimum time.
Your timing is a bit off.
Because we're doing fork, we can use IPC_PRIVATE instead of ftok (a bit cleaner).


Here is a refactored version. It is annotated with bugs/fixes.

I've improved the benchmark code.
I've added internal benchmark to show startup and latency.
I've combined both programs into one .c file.
Your fopen calls could be cleaned up.

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        fprintf(stderr,_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

#define Tmark       (tscgetf() - tscbeg)

double tsczero;

double
_tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tsczero;

    return sec;
}

#define tscgetf() \
    ({ \
        __asm__ __volatile__("nop\n" ::: "memory"); \
        _tscgetf(); \
    })

int base;
size_t size;
double t1;
double t2;
int shmid, sem;
char *shmPtr;
double tscbeg;
double tscsend[3];
double tscbest[3];
double tscrcv[3];

struct hdr {
    const char *sym;
    const char *reason;
};

#define HDRMAX  (sizeof(hdrs) / sizeof(hdrs[0]))

#define _HDRPUT(_fmt,_data...) \
    do { \
        totlen = fprintf(file,_fmt,_data); \
        for (;  totlen < lim;  ++totlen) \
            fputc(' ',file); \
    } while (0)
#define HDRPUT(_fmt,_data...) \
    do { \
        _HDRPUT(_fmt,_data); \
        ++ihdr; \
    } while (0)

void
result(int i,const char *pre,double tbest)
{
    int totlen;
    int lim = 12;

    char name[100];
    sprintf(name,"%s_result",pre);

    if (i == 0)
        unlink(name);

    FILE *file = fopen(name,"a");

    static struct hdr hdrs[] = {
        { "ELAPSED", "total elapsed time" },
        { "Tsend", "sender unlocks receiver" },
        { "Twait", "receiver becomes ready for input" },
        { "Trcv", "receiver released by sender" },
        { "Latency", "Trcv - Twait (time receiver is delayed)" },
        { "size", "buffer size" },
    };

    int ihdr;
    if (i == 0) {
        fprintf(file,"Legend:\n");
        for (ihdr = 0;  ihdr < HDRMAX;  ++ihdr) {
            _HDRPUT("%s",hdrs[ihdr].sym);
            fprintf(file,"-- %s\n",hdrs[ihdr].reason);
        }

        fprintf(file,"\n");
        for (ihdr = 0;  ihdr < HDRMAX;  ++ihdr)
            _HDRPUT("%s",hdrs[ihdr].sym);
        fprintf(file,"\n");
    }

    ihdr = 0;
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tbest);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscsend[0]);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[0]);

    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[1]);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[1] - tscrcv[0]);
#if 0
    HDRPUT("%d/%d",base,size);
#else
    fprintf(file,"%zu",size);
#endif
    fprintf(file,"\n");

    fclose(file);
}

#define COUNT 16

void
dobest(const char *pre,void (*fnc)(int i,int dtflg))
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE

    base = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        double tbest = 1e9;

        size = base;
        if ((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size + 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1)
            sysfault("dobest: shmget failure -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        shmPtr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

        // do multiple trials to minimize the effects of timeslicing and system
        // loading
        for (int iter = 3;  iter > 0;  --iter) {
            tscbeg = tscgetf();
            fnc(i,iter == 1);
            double tdif = t2 - t1;
            if (tdif < tbest) {
                tbest = tdif;
                memcpy(tscrcv,shmPtr,sizeof(tscrcv));
                memcpy(tscbest,tscsend,sizeof(tscbest));
            }
        }

        // record the best result
        result(i,pre,tbest);

        shmdt(shmPtr);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);

        base *= 4;
    }
}

void
pipeone(int i,int dtflg)
{
    int fd[2];
    int nread, pid, status;

    pipe(fd);
    fcntl(fd[1], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);
    fcntl(fd[0], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);

    char *buf = malloc(size);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // READ

        close(fd[1]);

        tscrcv[0] = Tmark;
        int mark = 1;
        while ((nread = read(fd[0], buf, size)) != 0) {
            if (mark)
                tscrcv[1] = Tmark;
            mark = 0;
        }

        memcpy(shmPtr,tscrcv,sizeof(tscrcv));

        exit(0);
    }

    // WRITE
    close(fd[0]);

    t1 = tscgetf();

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        buf[j] = '1';

    tscsend[0] = Tmark;
    write(fd[1], buf, size);
    close(fd[1]);

    wait(&status);

    t2 = tscgetf();

    free(buf);
}

key_t shm_keys[COUNT], sem_keys[COUNT];

void
shmone(int i,int dtflg)
{
    int pid, status;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        tscrcv[0] = Tmark;
        while (semctl(sem, 0, GETVAL) != 1);
        tscrcv[1] = Tmark;

// NOTE/BUG: not valid to copy from the shared buffer -- the whole point is to
// operate on the shared buffer directly!!!
#if 0
        char *str = (char *) malloc(size);
        strcpy(str, shmPtr);
        free(str);
        exit(1);

// NOTE/FIX: do _not_ copy out the buffer -- for testing purposes, we only want
// to measure the delivery time
#else
        size_t len = 0;
#if 0
        len = strlen(shmPtr);
#endif
        memcpy(shmPtr,tscrcv,sizeof(tscrcv));
        exit(len % 0x7f);
#endif
    }

    t1 = tscgetf();
#if 0
    char *str = (char *) malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
#else
    char *str = shmPtr;
#endif

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        str[j] = '1';
    str[size] = '\0';

#if 0
    strcpy(shmPtr, str);
#endif

    tscsend[0] = Tmark;
    semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, 1);
#if 0
    free(str);
#endif

    wait(&status);

    t2 = tscgetf();
}

void
pipeall(void)
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE

    dobest("pipe",pipeone);
}

void
shmall(void)
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE

    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        shm_keys[i] = ftok(".", (char) i);
        sem_keys[i] = ftok(".", 'a' + i);
    }

    dobest("shm",shmone);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    tsczero = tscgetf();

    if (argc < 1)
        sysfault("main: specify type: pipe or shm\n");

    do {
        char *cp = *argv;

        if (strcmp(cp,"pipe") == 0) {
            pipeall();
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(cp,"shm") == 0) {
            shmall();
            break;
        }

        sysfault("main: unknown type -- '%s'\n",cp);
    } while (0);

    return 0;
}


In the code above, I've used cpp conditionals to denote old vs. new code:
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through unifdef -k

Here is the output of ./program pipe:
Legend:
ELAPSED     -- total elapsed time
Tsend       -- sender unlocks receiver
Twait       -- receiver becomes ready for input
Trcv        -- receiver released by sender
Latency     -- Trcv - Twait (time receiver is delayed)
size        -- buffer size

ELAPSED     Tsend       Twait       Trcv        Latency     size
0.000212793 0.000097429 0.000125559 0.000162328 0.000036769 1
0.000167312 0.000104965 0.000125442 0.000147394 0.000021952 4
0.000177647 0.000096102 0.000093215 0.000128481 0.000035266 16
0.000106641 0.000080761 0.000077737 0.000096395 0.000018658 64
0.000204464 0.000163753 0.000112410 0.000148289 0.000035879 256
0.000147881 0.000060119 0.000144019 0.000166102 0.000022083 1024
0.000108481 0.000072081 0.000080240 0.000099838 0.000019598 4096
0.000156202 0.000130236 0.000145147 0.000173962 0.000028815 16384
0.000233014 0.000144926 0.000076950 0.000188236 0.000111286 65536
0.000605337 0.000425224 0.000079762 0.000537632 0.000457870 262144
0.002080624 0.001375300 0.000150789 0.001993695 0.001842906 1048576
0.009131487 0.005655973 0.000243503 0.008914248 0.008670745 4194304
0.036384772 0.021980127 0.000213079 0.035238290 0.035025211 16777216
0.142985735 0.072771127 0.000424021 0.137922121 0.137498100 67108864
0.572007428 0.292893437 0.000403933 0.553239097 0.552835164 268435456
2.276978512 1.176618786 0.000574158 2.220540762 2.219966604 1073741824


Here is the output of ./program shm:
Legend:
ELAPSED     -- total elapsed time
Tsend       -- sender unlocks receiver
Twait       -- receiver becomes ready for input
Trcv        -- receiver released by sender
Latency     -- Trcv - Twait (time receiver is delayed)
size        -- buffer size

ELAPSED     Tsend       Twait       Trcv        Latency     size
0.000181048 0.000081319 0.000126865 0.000152599 0.000025734 1
0.000277881 0.000079515 0.000165932 0.000177756 0.000011824 4
0.000191934 0.000081238 0.000126623 0.000134039 0.000007416 16
0.000201862 0.000080135 0.000124149 0.000135244 0.000011095 64
0.000183210 0.000080799 0.000107105 0.000113932 0.000006827 256
0.000146235 0.000085935 0.000112573 0.000119606 0.000007033 1024
0.000144176 0.000085737 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 4096
0.000235418 0.000100743 0.000136712 0.000148129 0.000011417 16384
0.000172821 0.000160697 0.000123424 0.000134592 0.000011168 65536
0.000201004 0.000241614 0.000122755 0.000129961 0.000007206 262144
0.000748101 0.000788737 0.000091531 0.000098554 0.000007023 1048576
0.002963725 0.003005338 0.000150246 0.000157523 0.000007277 4194304
0.011919764 0.011992419 0.000192575 0.000201370 0.000008795 16777216
0.047795073 0.047874544 0.000200046 0.000209144 0.000009098 67108864
0.190522428 0.190601263 0.000178723 0.000187669 0.000008946 268435456
0.757310083 0.757391226 0.000177408 0.000186831 0.000009423 1073741824


Here is the cleaned up source:
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        fprintf(stderr,_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

#define Tmark       (tscgetf() - tscbeg)

double tsczero;

double
_tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tsczero;

    return sec;
}

#define tscgetf() \
    ({ \
        __asm__ __volatile__("nop\n" ::: "memory"); \
        _tscgetf(); \
    })

int base;
size_t size;
double t1;
double t2;
int shmid, sem;
char *shmPtr;
double tscbeg;
double tscsend[3];
double tscbest[3];
double tscrcv[3];

struct hdr {
    const char *sym;
    const char *reason;
};

#define HDRMAX  (sizeof(hdrs) / sizeof(hdrs[0]))

#define _HDRPUT(_fmt,_data...) \
    do { \
        totlen = fprintf(file,_fmt,_data); \
        for (;  totlen < lim;  ++totlen) \
            fputc(' ',file); \
    } while (0)
#define HDRPUT(_fmt,_data...) \
    do { \
        _HDRPUT(_fmt,_data); \
        ++ihdr; \
    } while (0)

void
result(int i,const char *pre,double tbest)
{
    int totlen;
    int lim = 12;

    char name[100];
    sprintf(name,"%s_result",pre);

    if (i == 0)
        unlink(name);

    FILE *file = fopen(name,"a");

    static struct hdr hdrs[] = {
        { "ELAPSED", "total elapsed time" },
        { "Tsend", "sender unlocks receiver" },
        { "Twait", "receiver becomes ready for input" },
        { "Trcv", "receiver released by sender" },
        { "Latency", "Trcv - Twait (time receiver is delayed)" },
        { "size", "buffer size" },
    };

    int ihdr;
    if (i == 0) {
        fprintf(file,"Legend:\n");
        for (ihdr = 0;  ihdr < HDRMAX;  ++ihdr) {
            _HDRPUT("%s",hdrs[ihdr].sym);
            fprintf(file,"-- %s\n",hdrs[ihdr].reason);
        }

        fprintf(file,"\n");
        for (ihdr = 0;  ihdr < HDRMAX;  ++ihdr)
            _HDRPUT("%s",hdrs[ihdr].sym);
        fprintf(file,"\n");
    }

    ihdr = 0;
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tbest);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscsend[0]);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[0]);

    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[1]);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[1] - tscrcv[0]);
    fprintf(file,"%zu",size);
    fprintf(file,"\n");

    fclose(file);
}

#define COUNT 16

void
dobest(const char *pre,void (*fnc)(int i,int dtflg))
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE

    base = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        double tbest = 1e9;

        size = base;
        if ((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size + 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1)
            sysfault("dobest: shmget failure -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        shmPtr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

        // do multiple trials to minimize the effects of timeslicing and system
        // loading
        for (int iter = 3;  iter > 0;  --iter) {
            tscbeg = tscgetf();
            fnc(i,iter == 1);
            double tdif = t2 - t1;
            if (tdif < tbest) {
                tbest = tdif;
                memcpy(tscrcv,shmPtr,sizeof(tscrcv));
                memcpy(tscbest,tscsend,sizeof(tscbest));
            }
        }

        // record the best result
        result(i,pre,tbest);

        shmdt(shmPtr);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);

        base *= 4;
    }
}

void
pipeone(int i,int dtflg)
{
    int fd[2];
    int nread, pid, status;

    pipe(fd);
    fcntl(fd[1], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);
    fcntl(fd[0], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);

    char *buf = malloc(size);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // READ

        close(fd[1]);

        tscrcv[0] = Tmark;
        int mark = 1;
        while ((nread = read(fd[0], buf, size)) != 0) {
            if (mark)
                tscrcv[1] = Tmark;
            mark = 0;
        }

        memcpy(shmPtr,tscrcv,sizeof(tscrcv));

        exit(0);
    }

    // WRITE
    close(fd[0]);

    t1 = tscgetf();

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        buf[j] = '1';

    tscsend[0] = Tmark;
    write(fd[1], buf, size);
    close(fd[1]);

    wait(&status);

    t2 = tscgetf();

    free(buf);
}

key_t shm_keys[COUNT], sem_keys[COUNT];

void
shmone(int i,int dtflg)
{
    int pid, status;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        tscrcv[0] = Tmark;
        while (semctl(sem, 0, GETVAL) != 1);
        tscrcv[1] = Tmark;

// NOTE/BUG: not valid to copy from the shared buffer -- the whole point is to
// operate on the shared buffer directly!!!
        size_t len = 0;
        memcpy(shmPtr,tscrcv,sizeof(tscrcv));
        exit(len % 0x7f);
    }

    t1 = tscgetf();
    char *str = shmPtr;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        str[j] = '1';
    str[size] = '\0';

    tscsend[0] = Tmark;
    semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, 1);

    wait(&status);

    t2 = tscgetf();
}

void
pipeall(void)
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE

    dobest("pipe",pipeone);
}

void
shmall(void)
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE

    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        shm_keys[i] = ftok(".", (char) i);
        sem_keys[i] = ftok(".", 'a' + i);
    }

    dobest("shm",shmone);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    tsczero = tscgetf();

    if (argc < 1)
        sysfault("main: specify type: pipe or shm\n");

    do {
        char *cp = *argv;

        if (strcmp(cp,"pipe") == 0) {
            pipeall();
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(cp,"shm") == 0) {
            shmall();
            break;
        }

        sysfault("main: unknown type -- '%s'\n",cp);
    } while (0);

    return 0;
}


UPDATE:
I've done some considerable cleanup on the test program. Due to some objections, I've added some options:
-C<n> -- test count
-I<n> -- iteration count
-m<0/1> -- notification (1=msgsnd/msgrcv, 0=sem*)
-S<0/1> -- 1=pipe set maximum size (F_SETPIPE_SZ)
-x<0/1> -- 1=child scan/process data
-v<0/1> -- 1=copy results to stdout

It turns out that using sem* for notification [as posted here] is not as reliable as msgsnd/msgrcv [which is what I traditionally use]. Using sem* can produce a negative latency value for some tests. This indicates that the mechanism isn't robust [for some reason]. So, I replaced it with msgsnd/msgrcv
I added the -x option for force the receiver to "do work" on the buffer. This had a slight effect. As I mentioned, we want to measure the transfer time (and not the transfer time + processing time), so I'd leave off -x, but it's there for completeness.
Also, if no "test" argument is given, the program will run the "pipe" test and then the "shm" test sequentially (in subprocesses) as a convenience.
More details about the options are in the code:
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

int opt_C = 16;
int opt_I = 3;
int opt_m = 1;
int opt_S = 1;
int opt_x;
int opt_v;

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        fprintf(stderr,_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

#define Tmark       (tscgetf() - tscbeg)

double tsczero;

double
_tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tsczero;

    return sec;
}

#define barrier \
    __asm__ __volatile__("nop\n" ::: "memory"); \

#define tscgetf() \
    ({ \
        barrier; \
        _tscgetf(); \
    })

int base;
size_t size;
double t1;
double t2;
int shmid;
int sem;
char *shmPtr;
char *fake;
int forkflg;
double tscbeg;

double tscsend[3];
double tscbest[3];
double tscrcv[3];

struct msg {
    long msg_type;
    int msg_payload;
};
#define MSG_TYPE        17

enum {
    Tnotify
};

enum {
    Tready,
    Trunning,
};

char result_file[100];

struct hdr {
    const char *sym;
    const char *reason;
};

#define HDRMAX  (sizeof(hdrs) / sizeof(hdrs[0]))

#define _HDRPUT(_fmt,_data...) \
    do { \
        totlen = fprintf(xf,_fmt,_data); \
        for (;  totlen < lim;  ++totlen) \
            fputc(' ',xf); \
    } while (0)
#define HDRPUT(_fmt,_data...) \
    do { \
        _HDRPUT(_fmt,_data); \
        ++ihdr; \
    } while (0)

void
optshow(FILE *xf)
{
    fprintf(xf,"options:\n");
    fprintf(xf,"  C=%d -- test count\n",opt_C);
    fprintf(xf,"  I=%d -- iteration count\n",opt_I);
    fprintf(xf,"  m=%d -- notification (1=msgsnd/msgrcv, 0=sem*)\n",opt_m);
    fprintf(xf,"  S=%d -- 1=pipe set maximum size (F_SETPIPE_SZ)\n",opt_S);
    fprintf(xf,"  x=%d -- 1=child scan/process data\n",opt_x);
}

void
result(int i,const char *pre,double tbest)
{
    int totlen;
    int lim = opt_m ? 12 : 13;

    if (i == 0)
        unlink(result_file);

    FILE *xf = fopen(result_file,"a");

    static struct hdr hdrs[] = {
        { "ELAPSED", "total elapsed time" },
        { "Tnotify", "sender buffer filled -- receiver notified" },
        { "Tready", "receiver becomes ready for input" },
        { "Trunning", "receiver released by sender" },
        { "Latency", "Trunning - Tnotify (time receiver is delayed)" },
        { "size", "buffer size" },
    };

    int ihdr;
    if (i == 0) {
        fprintf(xf,"TEST: %s ...\n",pre);
        optshow(xf);
        fprintf(xf,"\n");

        fprintf(xf,"Legend:\n");
        for (ihdr = 0;  ihdr < HDRMAX;  ++ihdr) {
            _HDRPUT("%s",hdrs[ihdr].sym);
            fprintf(xf,"-- %s\n",hdrs[ihdr].reason);
        }

        fprintf(xf,"\n");
        for (ihdr = 0;  ihdr < HDRMAX;  ++ihdr)
            _HDRPUT("%s",hdrs[ihdr].sym);
        fprintf(xf,"\n");
    }

    ihdr = 0;
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tbest);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscbest[Tnotify]);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[Tready]);

    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[Trunning]);
    HDRPUT("%.9f",tscrcv[Trunning] - tscbest[Tnotify]);
    fprintf(xf,"%zu",size);
    fprintf(xf,"\n");

    fclose(xf);
}

void
result_show(void)
{
    char *av[3];
    pid_t pid;

    av[0] = "cat";
    av[1] = result_file;
    av[2] = NULL;

    if (opt_v) {
        if (result_file[0] == 0)
            sysfault("result_show: null result_file\n");

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("\n");
            execvp(av[0],av);
            sysfault("result_show: exec fault -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        }

        waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
    }
}

void
scan(char *buf,size_t len)
{

    if (opt_x)
        fake = memchr(buf,'2',len);
}

void
notify_open(void)
{

    if (opt_m)
        sem = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    else
        sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
}

void
notify_close(void)
{

    if (opt_m)
        msgctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);
    else
        semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);
}

void
notify_send(void)
{
    struct msg msg;

    tscsend[Tnotify] = Tmark;

    if (opt_m) {
        msg.msg_type = MSG_TYPE;
        msgsnd(sem,&msg,sizeof(msg) - sizeof(msg.msg_type),0);
    }
    else
        semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, 1);
}

void
notify_wait(void)
{
    struct msg msg;

    tscrcv[Tready] = Tmark;

    if (opt_m) {
        msgrcv(sem,&msg,sizeof(msg) - sizeof(msg.msg_type),MSG_TYPE,0);
    }
    else {
        while (semctl(sem, 0, GETVAL) != 1);
    }

    tscrcv[Trunning] = Tmark;
}

void
dobest(const char *pre,void (*fnc)(int i,int dtflg))
{
    // fd[0]=READ, fd[1]=WRITE

    if (! opt_v) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("dobest: %s ...\n",pre);
    }
    fflush(stdout);

    sprintf(result_file,"%s_result",pre);

    if (forkflg) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid != 0) {
            waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
            result_show();
            return;
        }
    }

    base = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < opt_C; i++) {
        double tbest = 1e9;

        size = base;
        if ((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size + 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1)
            sysfault("dobest: shmget failure -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        shmPtr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        notify_open();

        // do multiple trials to minimize the effects of timeslicing and system
        // loading
        for (int iter = opt_I;  iter > 0;  --iter) {
            tscbeg = tscgetf();
            barrier;

            fnc(i,iter == 1);

            double tdif = t2 - t1;
            if (tdif < tbest) {
                tbest = tdif;
                memcpy(tscrcv,shmPtr,sizeof(tscrcv));
                memcpy(tscbest,tscsend,sizeof(tscbest));
            }
        }

        // record the best result
        result(i,pre,tbest);

        shmdt(shmPtr);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        notify_close();

        base *= 4;
    }

    if (forkflg)
        exit(0);

    result_show();
}

void
pipeone(int i,int dtflg)
{
    int fd[2];
    ssize_t nread;
    int pid, status;

    pipe(fd);
    if (opt_S) {
        fcntl(fd[1], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);
        fcntl(fd[0], F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);
    }

    char *buf = malloc(size);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // READ

        close(fd[1]);

        tscrcv[0] = Tmark;
        int mark = 1;
        while (1) {
            nread = read(fd[0], buf, size);
            int sverr = errno;

            if (nread == 0)
                break;

            if (mark)
                tscrcv[1] = Tmark;
            mark = 0;

            if (nread < 0) {
                printf("pipeone: read error -- %s\n",strerror(sverr));
                break;
            }

            scan(buf,nread);
        }

        memcpy(shmPtr,tscrcv,sizeof(tscrcv));

        exit(0);
    }

    // WRITE
    close(fd[0]);

    t1 = tscgetf();

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        buf[j] = '1';

    tscsend[0] = Tmark;
    size_t off = 0;
    ssize_t xlen;
    for (;  off < size;  off += xlen) {
        xlen = write(fd[1], &buf[off], size - off);
        if (xlen < 0) {
            printf("pipeone: write error off=%zu size=%zu -- %s\n",
                off,size,strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
    }
    close(fd[1]);

    waitpid(pid,&status,0);

    t2 = tscgetf();

    free(buf);
}

void
shmone(int i,int dtflg)
{
    int pid, status;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        notify_wait();

// NOTE/BUG: not valid to copy from the shared buffer -- the whole point is to
// operate on the shared buffer directly!!!
        scan(shmPtr,size);
        memcpy(shmPtr,tscrcv,sizeof(tscrcv));
        exit(0);
    }

    t1 = tscgetf();
    char *str = shmPtr;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        str[j] = '1';
    str[size] = '\0';

    notify_send();

    waitpid(pid,&status,0);

    t2 = tscgetf();
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    setlinebuf(stdout);
    tsczero = tscgetf();
    printf("main (%d)\n",getpid());

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'C':  // number of trials
            opt_C = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'I':  // number of iterations
            opt_I = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'm':  // notifcation message type
            opt_m = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'S':  // pipe sender should issue F_SETPIPE_SZ
            opt_S = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'v':  // dump log files to stdout
            opt_v = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'x':  // child should scan data
            opt_x = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        default:
            sysfault("main: unknown option -- '%s'\n",cp - 2);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (! opt_v)
        optshow(stdout);

    do {
        cp = *argv;

        if (argc < 1) {
            forkflg = 1;
            dobest("pipe",pipeone);
            dobest("shm",shmone);
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(cp,"pipe") == 0) {
            dobest("pipe",pipeone);
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(cp,"shm") == 0) {
            dobest("shm",shmone);
            break;
        }

        sysfault("main: unknown type -- '%s'\n",cp);
    } while (0);

    return 0;
}


By "choosing the best time" and never touching any of the data when it's being sent or when it's received you've completely ignored all the costs of shared memory (page faults, TLB misses, cache misses, ...). It's like you're deliberately fabricating misinformation, like "Oh, I can do literally nothing while ignoring everything that actually matters, and it's faster!".

The question arose, if I still need to read data from a common memory segment, I must first write it down and then read it. Or writing and reading should be parallel, since as I understand it, pipes are synchronized by default and work in parallel.

Nicely done! The variadic macros make gcc complain loudly, but for their purpose work very well. Tired old i7-gen2, 1G example - 1 sec on pipe, .64 on shm. It is indeed faster and here is the data to prove it.

@Brendan I've added a more capable version with test options. Adding processing of the data had little to no effect on the results. And, it's not what we really want to measure anyway (as I've mentioned). Also, again, note the "logical" section at the top. The "pipe" version does two extra copy operations on the data that the "shm" doesn't. Side note: I've been using shared buffers in R/T mission critical systems for two decades. This answer is backed up by testing I've done over the years.

@CraigEstey: There's 2 main purposes: security/sandboxing and scalability/performance. For security you need to "copy then validate (then use)" to ensure an untrusted sender can't tamper with the data after validation. For scalability; the processing needs to cost more than the communication (otherwise it's better for sender to process itself instead of sending); and in the "expensive processing" case moving data out of the buffer so sender can send while you process often improves parallelism. Your code fails to measure any realistic scenario. It's benchmarking "should have used one process".


It is necessary to compare the transfer time and come to the conclusion that the shared memory segments work faster with big data.

That's called "begging the question" - assuming a conclusion is true without proving it (and then modifying tests to force the assumption to be true later).

But it turns out the opposite. What is the problem in my code?

Nothing is wrong with your code. Sometimes unproven assumptions are false assumptions, and sometimes forcing tests to match unproven assumptions is the basis of self-delusion (even if it's students forcing tests to match what a teacher wanted, causing a teacher's self-delusion). Note that "my teacher is correct" is another unproven assumption that may be (and often is) false.
For your specific code:

in theory; the kernel copying data to/from a buffer in kernel space when reading/writing to the pipe costs approximately the same as you copying data to/from your shared memory yourself. However, shared memory increases the amount of virtual memory you're using which increases the cost of fork(), and the underlying memory used by the kernel as a buffer for pipe is immune to "translation changes" in user-space and would have fewer TLB misses; so you'd expect pipes to be better for these reasons.

the synchronization is mostly the same for both cases. E.g. a process blocked waiting for data to arrive on a pipe and then being woken when the data arrives is essentially the same as a process blocked waiting for a semaphore that gets woken up when the semaphore can be acquired. This includes the same number of system calls and "user -> kernel -> user" transitions.

there are no other "non-superficial" differences.


In other words, you should expect that shared memory is slower.
You can change this by moving the fork() out of the loop and only doing it once; like pid = fork(); if (pid == 0) { for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) { ... } else /* pid != 0 */ { for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) { ... } }. This will reduce the memory management differences that make shared memory worse. However, this change will also change the synchronization and may allow pipes to do "one process sends while the other process reads in parallel" (rather than a purely "only one process can actually do anything at any time with no parallelism at all" pattern) and cause pipes to be significantly faster than shared memory because of parallelism.
To fix the parallelism differences; you could implement your own FIFO queue in shared memory so that newer data can be put on the queue while older data is being taken from the queue. If you do this you will have reinvented pipes and should have fully reinforced the natural/expected "exact same work with irrelevant superficial differences = the exact same performance" relationship.
Of course "shared memory is faster" isn't an option that can be expected. It's built on a myth that involves avoiding kernel system calls, including avoiding the need to tell kernel "I must wait for data to arrive so block me" and avoiding the need to tell kernel "That other process needs to be stop waiting and be unblocked because data arrived". To artificially manufacture the myth that shared memory is better you need to either move the scheduler into user-space; or introduce additional background work so that the process/es do other useful work instead of blocking. That means polling; like "while(true) { do_some_other_work(); if( data_received() ) { handle_received_data(); } }"; where the communication never involves the kernel. However, for a fair test you would have to do the same for pipes, and "pipes without kernel involvement" is the exact same code as "FIFO queue in shared memory"; so we never reach any kind of fair comparison where shared memory is capable of having higher performance.

That's the write-up that I couldn't quite put my finger on, but I think it hits the nail on the head. Heaven forbid the "teacher" may be a bit confused about the subject they are attempting to teach -- certainly wouldn't be the first time here.The whole question and set of results begged the answer of why do you expect shared memory to be faster? The learning involved is "because my teacher says so" -- doesn't make it true.

@DavidC.Rankin Okay, guys, I understand you. I also don't like to believe in anything so blindly, but since the teacher is more experienced and qualified, I believed in it.
And for some reason, after several hours of operation of my laptop, the time difference became quite small. And sometimes shared memory segments even work faster.
But anyway, thank you so much for your help and time spent.

And actually I could have faked the results, but I'm so interested in this subject (operating systems), so I wanted to understand this topic.

@DavidC.Rankin Actually, the teacher is correct. Shared memory is faster. OP's programs weren't measuring correctly. I've built my career on using shared memory buffers for speed and reduced latency for R/T systems. I've posted an answer.

@CraigEstey thank you for the education. I've not timed either, but have seen enough "professor" incorrectness to always require data over assumptions. I'll definitely drink from the well of knowledge you have provided.
